# Dynamically bind Views into a ContainerControl with MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding

I've been learning the MVVM pattern with [Josh Smith's article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) and I want to create a classic layout with some links to the right (managed with commands) so when I click one I can show my view to the right into a tab control (inside it there is a ContentControl).

This is simple when I use a DataTemplate with the specific View and ViewModel I want to show on screen like this.

```
<!-- this section into my MainWindow's resources file -->
<DataTemplate xmlns:vm='clr-namespace:WpfFramework.ViewModels'
              xmlns:vw='clr-namespace:WpfFramework.Views'
              DataType="{x:Type vm:MySpecificViewModel }" >        
    <vw:MySpecificView />
</DataTemplate>
```

But, I want something more generic. I mean that my mainWindow should not know a specific View nor a specific ViewModel. It should only know that it binds to some commands and has a tab control which shows "some view". Every sample including [Josh Smith's article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) seems to have limited universe of views and viewmodels, that's great with a sample.

So, how can I tell my ContentControl that some view (with its corresponding viewModel) is gonna be there without being so specific (without "burning" into the mainView the concrete types)?

best regards
Rodrigo

PD. I have tryed with base a ViewModel and Base View but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your main View, bind a `ContentControl` to a generic `ViewModelBase` property

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentPage}" />
```

`CurrentPage` would be defined in the main ViewModel as a `ViewModelBase` object, and to switch pages you simply set `CurrentPage` to whatever you want.

So when you click on something like the `HomePageCommand`, the main ViewModel would execute `CurrentPage = new HomePageViewModel();` providing that `HomePageViewModel` inherits from `ViewModelBase`.

I wrote something a little while ago that shows some samples [here](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/28/switching-between-viewsusercontrols-using-mvvm/) if you're interested

Comment: Hi Rachel, thanks for the suggestion (by the way, could you correct your link?). I have tried that but I cannot figure out how can I relate a HomePageViewModel with its corresponding HomePageView?

Comment: @Rodrigo You are doing it correctly in your question. In your application resources, define the data templates which maps each ViewModel to a specified View. Usually I put the mappings in App.xaml under `<Application.Resources>`. Another alternative is to put the DataTemplates in a ResourceDictionary, and load the ResourceDictionaries into the application's MergedDictionaries at runtime. I use this method if ResourceDictionaries are loaded dynamically or if they exist in other dlls. (I also fixed the link)

Comment: I have a question on [your example](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/28/switching-between-viewsusercontrols-using-mvvm/). Is there a View involved? I mean what if I have 300 views, am I supposed to explicit that markup on my mainView?

Comment: Really!!!?? so, I'll have 300 DataTemplates in my corporate project. ok, I'm assimilating that...

Comment: @Rodrigo Yes, if you had 300 ViewModels and 300 UserControls for your Views, you would need 300 DataTemplates to map the two of them together. Don't forget though, the View doesn't have to be a UserControl - It can also be just the DataTemplate. Often if the ViewModel is something small I will simply write the View as the DataTemplate wherever needed. For example, take a Customer object that has Addresses, Phones, and Emails. I would have a UserControl View for my Customer object, but within the UserControl.Resources I would define the Address/Phone/Email Views as DataTemplates.

Comment: Thanks @Rachel, well I got shocked a little. I'm comming from an ASP.NET MVC and WindowsForms environment and I thought I would be more straight foreward to have the View-ViewModel link without so much code. I'm still wondering about [Josh Smith's article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090097) commentary: "In more complex scenarios, it is possible to programmatically select the view". Best regards

Comment: @Rodrigo It really isn't that much code, especially if most of your Views are DataTemplates and not UserControls. Each DataTemplate only  needs to exist in the application once. The application wouldn't know how to draw a ViewModel otherwise. In a large or modular application there are other ways to add the Resources dynamically through `Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries`. In the past I've used this to add ResourceDictionaries found with Reflection on dll's in the folder, and I've done it with Modules where modules will load up their Resources when they load.

Comment: Thanks @Rachel you convinced me. this is the answer. best regards

Comment: @Rodrigo I think I might have misunderstood your question, but I'm glad I was able to help you afterall :) Goodluck with your project.